# Angular test cannot find the open dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular component (`HostComponent`) that contains some buttons which should open a dialog. I am writing a test for this `HostComponent` using Angular's `TestBed`. In the test, I select the button, click it and try to assert that a dialog is opened. When I run the test in browser (since Karma serves the test), I can see that a dialog successfully opens, however my test still fails with the error:

```
Error: Failed to find element matching one of the following queries:
    (MatDialogHarness with host element matching selector: ".mat-dialog-container")
```

Here's a drilled down version of the spec:

```
describe('HostComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;
    let loader: HarnessLoader;

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [HostComponent, MyTestDialogComponent],
            providers: [FormBuilder],
            imports: [MatDialogModule, NoopAnimationsModule, MatAutocompleteModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatSelectModule, MatInputModule]
        }).createComponent(WidgetGroupConfigComponent);

        loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    const buttonWithText = (text: string) => {
        const allButtons: HTMLButtonElement[] = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button');
        const allButtonsArr = [...allButtons];
        return allButtonsArr.find(button => button.innerText === text);
    };

    it('Opens the dialog when button is clicked', fakeAsync(async () => {
        const testButton = buttonWithText('TestTimberDevice01')!;
        expect(testButton).toBeDefined(); // passes

        testButton.click();
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const dialog = await loader.getHarness(MatDialogHarness); // fails here
        expect(dialog).toBeDefined();

    }));
});
```

Here's the screenshot that shows that the dialog is opened even though the tests fail:

[image]

I'm really quite confused with Angular's testing features and I've tried asking a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66872371/angular-how-to-test-that-clicking-on-a-component-nativeelement-opens-a-dialog) with no luck, so I'm really hoping to be luckier this time.

Comment: check this link : https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses

Comment: Why? I'm sorry, I just read the whole link (even though I had read it before) but I didn't find anything that could help with the problem I describe above. Do you have something specific in mind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dialogs are rendered outside of the component fixture, so the fix here would be to use documentRootLoader instead of the simple fixture one

```
  loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.documentRootLoader(fixture);
```

Comment: I've no idea why this isn't in the documentation for MatDialog or Harnesses! The only place it exists in the Angular teams "documentation" is their examples of MatDialogHarness tests. They don't call it out though so it's pretty hard to spot. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/components-examples/material/dialog/dialog-harness/dialog-harness-example.spec.ts#L20